# What is the use of LeftHandSideExpression in for-in loop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

The spec [goes](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2)

> Left-Hand-Side Expressions
>
> ```
> LeftHandSideExpression :
>     NewExpression
>     CallExpression
> ```

Then it [goes again](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6)

> Iteration Statements
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> IterationStatement :
>     do Statement while ( Expression );
>     while ( Expression ) Statement
>     for ( ExpressionNoInopt ; Expressionopt ; Expressionopt ) Statement
>     for ( var VariableDeclarationListNoIn ; Expressionopt ; Expressionopt ) Statement
>     for ( LeftHandSideExpression in Expression ) Statement
>     for ( var VariableDeclarationNoIn in Expression ) Statement
> ```

Question:

- What is the use of this:

  ```
   for ( LeftHandSideExpression in Expression ) Statement
  ```

Comment: You can use it for object iteration.

Answer (score 3):

From [here](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/01/04/exploring-javascript-for-in-loops/):

> In ECMAScript terms a LeftHandSideExpression is any expression that
>   resolves to a property reference (think anything that can go on the
>   left hand side of an assignment). On each iteration, the name of the
>   next property gets assigned to the evaluation of the
>   LeftHandSideExpression. It’s perfectly valid for the
>   LeftHandSideExpression to resolve to a different reference on each
>   iteration.  **Occasionally this is useful – even elegant – for example getting an array of property names is now a breeze**:

```
var myObj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, myKeys = [], i=0;

for (myKeys[i++] in myObj);

myKeys; //['a','b','c'];
```

Comment: It's like someone can't make up their mind if this is a good or bad answer.

Comment: "getting an array of property names is now a breeze" --- `Object.keys()`

Comment: Nice, but your example uses an index expression whereas the specs says LeftSideExpression is either a CallExpression or a NewExpression

Comment: Never mind, just found it: `CallExpression: CallExpression [ Expression ]`

Comment: @AlekseyBykov but it still does not show how `NewExpression` can be used there.